# Where is my error occuring Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I can run my game perfectly fine, however when it stops I get this error

!CompareApproximately (det, 1.0F, .005f)

UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()

From what I've been able to find I think I would be able to fix it, however I can't find where the error is occuring.  I would include code, but I'm not sure what would be relevant.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you debug to check where the error is occuring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is unrelated to your game code. This is just a small bug within the Unity Editor's internal GUI coding. Although, I thought they had patched this particular one up with the lastest hotfix release. Ensure that you are running the latest version of Unity.

Comment: OK, I thought that updating had fixed it, but it's just appeared again, what could be causing this other than Unity?  Or should I just ignore it as it isn't causing my game to crash?

Comment: By the latest version do you mean the 4.6 beta?

Comment: I am currently running v4.5.5 and don't seem to have any problem.

Comment: Well it's not stopping my game from running so I'll just wait and see if 4.6 fixes it, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're due for a Unity Update.